# R xlab and ylab in xts plot

Tags: r, plot, xts

Plotting an xts should be really easy, but I can't seem to get the xlab, and ylab to work..

```
ylab="Price"
xlab="Date"


plot(x = basket[, 1], lty="dotted", xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, col = "mediumblue", lwd = 2) 
title("Cumulative")
```

This will plot the figure, but without any labels on the x- and y-axis.

There must be an easy solution to this. The plot looks as it should besides that issue. I have tried with xts.plot, zoo.plot, xyplot but none seem to do the trick.

Data sample

```
structure(c(1, 1.01463414634146, 0.926829268292683, 0.970731707317073, 
0.953658536585366, 1, 0.998263888888889, 1.01159722222222, 1.05076388888889, 
1.05034722222222, 1, 1.00178890876565, 0.985688729874776, 1.04293381037567, 
1.04651162790698, 1, 0.976675478152698, 0.990359197636448, 1.06515316436013, 
1.04571606282071), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946944000, 
947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("new.close", "new.close.1", "new.close.2", "new.close.3"
    )))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `plot.zoo`, not `zoo.plot`.  These all work for me:

```
library(xts)

plot(as.zoo(basket[, 1]), xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")

plot.zoo(basket[, 1], xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")

library(lattice)
xyplot(basket[, 1], xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(basket[, 1]) + xlab("X") + ylab("Y")
```

### Note

```
basket <-
structure(c(1, 1.01463414634146, 0.926829268292683, 0.970731707317073, 
0.953658536585366, 1, 0.998263888888889, 1.01159722222222, 1.05076388888889, 
1.05034722222222, 1, 1.00178890876565, 0.985688729874776, 1.04293381037567, 
1.04651162790698, 1, 0.976675478152698, 0.990359197636448, 1.06515316436013, 
1.04571606282071), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946944000, 
947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("new.close", "new.close.1", "new.close.2", "new.close.3"
    )))
```

Comment: Something is clearly off with my xts plot settings for xts. None of them plots anything on the X and Y axis. I did try and remove the heading of the interval for which the plot was taken over, and that must have messed up something.  The ggplot2 does work though, so I guess I will have to work with that then. Thx!

Comment: Start a fresh instance of R using `R --vanilla` to be sure that nothing is pulled in.  Then copy and paste `basket `from the Note at the end of the answer and then copy and paste the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be exactly what you had in mind, but it gets the job done. Plus, you get to work with **ggplot2** which way better than the standard plotting system. In addition, I am using **ggfortify** which extends `ggplot()` capabilities to handle time series.

```r
library(xts)
library(zoo)
library(ggfortify)   
library(ggplot2)

myts = structure( 
  c(1, 1.01463414634146, 0.926829268292683, 0.970731707317073, 
    0.953658536585366, 1, 0.998263888888889, 1.01159722222222, 1.05076388888889, 
    1.05034722222222, 1, 1.00178890876565, 0.985688729874776, 1.04293381037567, 
    1.04651162790698, 1, 0.976675478152698, 0.990359197636448, 1.06515316436013, 
    1.04571606282071), 
  class = c("xts", "zoo"), 
  index = structure(c(946944000, 947030400, 
                      947116800, 947203200, 
                      947462400), 
                    tzone = "UTC", 
                    tclass = "Date"), 
  .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
                               c("new.close", 
                                 "new.close.1", 
                                 "new.close.2", 
                                 "new.close.3" ) ) 
)

autoplot( myts[ , 1], xlab = "Date", ylab = "Price" )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>